# Disable/enable ProcessCmdKey

Tags: c#

I have C# WinForms app where i use

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
```

Is it any option to enable/disable this method with check box? Example :

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(checkBox1.Checked) TURN_ON ProcessCmdKey
    else TURN_OFF ProcessCmdKey
 }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't do anything if the checkbox is not checked:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
   if(!checkBox1.Checked) {
      return false;
   }
   else {
      // my logic
   }
}
```

Comment: It not resolving my problem. I need to disable/enable ProcessCmdKey with checkbox